# Objective-C: __block not working

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

I could not figure out how to change the value of `results` inside the success block. I use `__block` like some post suggests but `results` is forever nil. I set breakpoint inside of block and make sure that `JSON` is not nil, which download data as I expected.

I am using AFNetworking library if that's relevant.

```
+(NSArray *)eventsByCityID:(NSString *)cityID startIndex:(NSUInteger)start count:(NSUInteger)count
{
    __block NSArray *results = nil;

    [[DoubanHTTPClient sharedClient] getPath:@"event/list" parameters:@{@"loc":dataSingleton.cityID} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSON) {
        results = [JSON valueForKey:@"events"];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"download events error: %@ \n\n",error);
    }];

    return results;
}
```

Comment: Try a fun experiment: put a breakpoint in the `results = [JSON valueForKey:@"events"]` block, and put a breakpoint at the return statement. See which one happens first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More likely than not, that [very poorly named] method `getPath:parameters:success:failure:` is asynchronous.

Thus, you need to tell something in the success block that the value has changed.  I.e.

```
^{
     [something yoManGotEvents:[JSON valueForKey:@"events"]];
 }
```

(Methods shouldn't be prefixed with `get` outside of very special circumstances.  Third party libraries with lots of API using that prefix outside of said circumstances raise question as to what other system specific patterns they may not be following.)

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's indeed asynchronous. I have to move my mapping code into success block now

Comment: `yoManGotEvents` could be better named I guess?

Comment: Yeah-- does follow conventions, though. ;)